# Not recognizing letters properly

Tags: python, image, algorithm, pixel

I wanted to create a small script, that will separate letters from an image of a document. So far i have a picture of two letters, and a set of functions that compare each pixel, if there are no pixels that are in the previous letters, create a letter, otherwise add the pixel to the letter. I have tried to debug it for an hour already, but have no idea what could be wrong. Here is a part of my code:

```
def findChars():
    im = Image.open("img-190.gif")
    letters = []
    for x in range(im.size[0]):
        for y in range(im.size[1]):
            px = im.getpixel((x,y))
            if(px == 0):#black
                found = False
                for letter in letters:
                    for pixel in letter.pix:
                        if(isNextTo((x,y),pixel) == True):
                            found = True
                            letter.pix +=((x,y),)
                            #print len(letter.pix)
                            break
                if(found == False):
                    letters.append(Letter((x,y)))
                    print "Appended"

    print len(letters)
```

The algorythm i am implementing:
Since i can assume that all letters are separate, i can go through all the pixels and group them into letters. I check if a pixel has any neighbors that are already in a letter group. If the answer is yes, i add it to the same group, if not i create another. At the end i have groups of pixels that are separate.

The problem is that it is not adding them correctly. Having two letters on the picture, it finds 49 groups(letters).

Here is my other function code:

```
def isNextTo(spix,qpix):
    DIST = 1
    if(qpix[0]< spix[0]-DIST or qpix[0]> spix[0]+DIST):
        return False
    if(qpix[1]< spix[1]-DIST or qpix[1]> spix[1]+DIST):
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: And Letter is just a class with a tuple of xy tuples inside

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do (the bigger picture)? Something along the lines of OCR? The problem you seem to be describing (pattern recognition, computer vision) is a _very_ hard one and most likely is best solved by an existing 3rd party library.

Comment: i know, there are many other libaries for that, but i wanted to group the pixels into letters. Can you tell me what i am doing wrong in the code?

Comment: No, because it's not clear from your question what algorithm you're trying to implement. The question remains, _why_ do you want to group pixels into letters? To achieve what? As I said, that's a very hard problem, it's unlikely you'll be able to solve that yourself.

Comment: the algorythm: go through all the pixels, if a pixel is next to a pixel in a letter, add that pixel to that group, otherwise, create a new letter and add that pixel there. Grouping pixels into letters enables me to divide the picture into single letters. Then i can compare the separate letters with my examples, to guess. But i am simply asking about the grouping, not about comparing letters.

Comment: But you're going through the pixels scanning columns; why would you think you already know about the pixels next to the one you're examining? Look at the letter Z or S; notice anything about the pixels in the first column?

Comment: What @Wooble said. The problem isn't your code as such, it's that your algorithm can't work. Also, consider for example the letter `i` (lowercase i). How could that algorithm possibly recognize the dot and the stem as being part of the same letter?

Comment: thank you Wooble, i guess running a function that combines the groups will solve the problem

Comment: @LukasGraf i only have capital letters for now.

Comment: @coolbartek You are not going to write a simple script that performs OCR. Seriously, this remains an area of active industrial research. Get a book on the subject, read it, then come back.

Comment: I was just trying to get more familiar with python, i know i don't know much about the subject. Is trying to make something in order to learn that bad? I'm sure all of you made implementations of algorithms, where you need, there are much better ones available.

Comment: @coolbartek I _think_ what you wanted your algorithm to do is this: Group the image in areas of contiguous pixels. That is pretty similar to what [Flood Fill algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) do, maybe use that as a starting point.

Comment: @LukasGraf thank you, that is also a good starting point, didn't think of that one

Comment: @coolbartek No, that's not bad at all, nobody is judging you. It's just that you picked a **very** hard problem field that universities and companies with million dollar budgets still are trying to solve. Like robotics, speech recognition, machine translation, ... That's why it's not suited very well to learn Python with: The problem itself is simply to difficult.

Comment: @coolbartek: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321899/how-to-determine-regions-of-pixels-with-a-shared-value-using-pil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I implemented an algorithm for finding connected shapes in an image, more out of interest and for practicing Python which was new to me back then. The basic idea was this:

- scan all lines of an image. In each line, generate a list of tuples that mark consecutive pixels that share a property (color, brightness, whatever). Each tuple looks like `(start x position, end x position, y position)`.
- after that, compare all such tuples and form groups of related tupels. Two tuples are moved to the same group if their y coordinate differs by one and their x ranges overlap.
- repeat merging tuples into groups until you find no tuples that *intersect* and are in a different group (you have to merge groups if you find this, obviously). The groups you have found are your objects/letters/whatever/separate regions.

I don't think this is a complicated strategy and I'm sure this algorithm has been done zilions of times and maybe even has a name and entry on Wikipedia. The basic problem it solves is that two groups of seemingly unrelated pixel ranges can form one group later when you detect a connection by means of other groups/pixel ranges in different lines. A good example of this is the number `2`. At first the algorithm may detect 8 groups, one for each line. Then it will merge the groups into less and less groups by means of the middle sections until only one group remains.